# Clear form from referenced file after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that is being processed by a JQuery script in a separate file and I want to clear the user's input after they click submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#assign_form'); // contact form
    var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button
    var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
        // sending ajax request through jQuery
        $.ajax({
            url: '/mySite/assign_form_submit.php', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert.html("<p>The form assignment has been sent and you have been copied on the email.</p>").fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('SUBMIT'); // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And my HTML looks something like this:

```
<form name="assign_form" id="assign_form" action="" method="post">

<input name="form_name" type="text">
<input name="email" type="text">

<div class="alert"></div>

<div id="submit_btn;">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="reset" type="reset">CLEAR THE FORM</button>
</div>
```

When the submit button is pressed, JQuery processes the form nicely. It doesn't refresh the page (which is what I want) but I can't get it to clear the form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your success event to reset the form

```
 $('#assign_form')[0].reset.click();
```

Note that this will only work when you have a reset button in your form. If you remove your reset button then you have to use

```
 $('#assign_form')[0].reset();
```

Comment: I replaced form.trigger('reset'); with what you suggested and it didn't work and now it won't reset the submit button text.

Comment: That's because you already have a reset button. Change to ` $('#assign_form')[0].reset.click();` I updated my answer to accommodate both scenarios.

Comment: Has anyone every told you that you're brilliant? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling reset on the form instead of triggering a reset event

```
form[0].reset(); // reset form
```